# look for image that has src from a particular site using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, match, src

I need to remove all images on a page that has the source from staticflickr.com using jQuery.
Could someone please help?

```
<img class="colorbox-194" src="http://farm8.**staticflickr.com**/7107/7143029237_13d20551a2.jpg" alt="the stride (explore) by stephane (got my camera back!!)">
```

img like above will be removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("img").filter(function() {
    return /^https?:\/\/(\w+.)?staticflickr.com\//.test(this.src);
}).hide();​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7KbCF/1/